# I want use Fastlane tools automation for Android, IOS and as well as for PHP also

Tags: php, android, ios, fastlane

I searched on google but not found any resources regarding this.
Can you please guide or provide any source to use Fastlane Tools with PHP?
In which platform i can install Fastlane for Windows or Linux. 
Can we manage Fastlane command using php?